# What are structured unstructured and semistructured data in Distributed Storage System

Tags: database, structured-data, cloud-storage

When learning **Distributed Storage System**,I faced a basic question: what are structured unstructured and semistructured data and their differeces.I already know simple differences between them, What I want to know are how to differ them inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structured Data is SQL like structures where the number of fields (columns) is fixed and every entry in the collection (table) has the same structure. References to other collections/tables are 'hardwired' via foreign keys.

Unstructured Data is like MongoDB where a collection is a loose association of documents which do not require to have the same structure. Each document can have different elements and references to other documents can be ad hoc.

Semi-structured systems are various hybrids of the two. For example Google's Firebase repository each document must have the same elements; however, relationships are ad hoc. Semi-structured data often include semantics like inheritance and isA vs. hasA relationships.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer at first.I do not doubt on your answer's theory, but I questioned a detail about MongoDB.In this post [structured-vs-unstructured-data](http://www.datamation.com/big-data/structured-vs-unstructured-data.html), it described the documents handled by MongoDB is semi-structured data.I confused about NoSQL on what is the data type that they faced.

Comment: MongoDB allows you to have documents with different objects (key:values) in the same collection. Other databases like Firestore do not. Every document in a collection has the same keys (obviously different values).